# Reuse a database from an old version

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, adt

I'm about to completely refresh my app. I made it with ADT, ActionbarSherlock and SlidingMenu, and I am switching to Android Studio with Appcompat and Nav Drawer (as you see, a total change). This means that I'm doing it from scratch, and only reusing the calculation classes and a couple of layouts.

In fact, my plan is to switch from only offline database storage to offline database with an optional cloud synchronization. There will definitely be be changes regarding database (just a global online id and an author id).

Now, my question is, is there a procedure to avoid losing the information (both database and app private folders) of my app? I added the same package name, the version is add to the previous one, and is signed with the same key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is updated through the Play Store, then the existing databases / SharedPreferences will remain.

Comment: Oh, ok, that was pretty straightforward, then. Thanks